# Error while installing tweepy on windows for python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7, tweepy

I have downloaded Tweepy for python 2.7 using the link:
 https://github.com/tweepy/tweepy

Refered this for installing the same:
[Error installing tweepy on windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20460177/error-installing-tweepy-on-windows)

But getting error while installing Tweepy. Plese help me out!!

Error:
The application has failed to start because its side-by-side configuration is in
correct. Please see the application event log or use the command-line sxstrace.e
xe tool for more detail.

Comment: Could you post the full error log ? maybe a screenshot of your command prompt ?

Comment: That is the only error I'm getting. I cant post the screenshot as I dont have 10 reputation points :( @AJK

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like this is not a tweepy issue, rather it is a windows issue.

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2525435

The issue state that the issue is with the C runtime libraries and visual studio.

`python setup.py install` must be trying to compile some cython code inside `tweepy` - which may be needed for performance issues. And while compiling this, it is using the conflicting C runtime library.

The link above explains a method to change registry keys necessary to fix this issue - but I personally hate registry edits, and prefer either:

- Uninstall all versions of Visual Studio and C runtume libraries and reinstall them

OR

- Use python compiler for microsoft (http://www.microsoft.com/en-in/download/details.aspx?id=44266) which will install a C compiler specifically for cython. This will have it's own command prompt - use this command prompt to run `python setup.py install`. The command prompt is good because it sets paths and environment variables correctly for you to avoid weird problems like this.